# Spark SQL not recognizing \d+

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to use the `regex_extract` function to get the last three digits in a string `ABCDF1_123` with:

```
regexp_extrach('ABCDF1_123', 'ABCDF1_(\d+)', 1)
```

and it does not capture the group.  If I change the function call to:

```
regexp_extrach('ABCDF1_123', 'ABCDF1_([0-9]+)', 1)
```

it works.  Can anyone give me some insight in to why?  I am also grabbing the data from a Postgres database using a JDBC connection.

Comment: Hello, could you please add a minimal executable code example displaying the behaviour?

Comment: use raw string to the pattern `r'ABCDF1_(\d+)'`, otherwise `\d` is treated as a literal `d`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran the `regexp_extract` and both of them are giving the same output as shown below

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit, when, col, regexp_extract

l = [('ABCDF1_123')]
rdd = sc.parallelize(l)
sample = rdd.map(lambda x: Row(name=x))
sample_df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(sample)

not_working = r'ABCDF1_(\d+)'
working = r'ABCDF1_([0-9]+)'

sample_df.select(regexp_extract('name',not_working,1).alias('not_working'),
                 regexp_extract('name',working,1).alias('working')).show(10)


+-----------+-------+
|not_working|working|
+-----------+-------+
|        123|    123|
+-----------+-------+
```

Is this what you are looking for?